# How does training of sklearn Stacking metaclassifier work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html) it is said that metaclassifier is trained through `cross_val_predict`. From my perspective it means that data is splitten by folds, and all base estimators predict values on one fold, trained on all other folds. And that procedure goes for every fold. Then metaclassifier is trained on predictions of base estimators on these folds. Is it correct? If so, doesn't it contradict to

> Note that `estimators_` are fitted on the full `X`

in the way that base estimators are trained on several folds, not full `X`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no contradiction, because `estimators_` is not used when training the metaclassifier.  After the cross-val-predictions are made, you don't actually have fitted base estimators (or rather, you have multiple copies of each, depending on your `cv` parameter).  For predicting on new data, you need a single fitted copy of each base estimator; those are obtained by fitting on the full `X`, and are stored in the attribute `estimators_`.